# Calculating total resistance between two points (triangle resistor network)

Tags: resistors, network

I want to calculate the total resistance between the 2 points: A, B.

I've tried using the Delta-Wye method, but I'm not sure how to apply it to my problem since there's 6 resistors and not 3 (usually seen in tutorials).

[image: DWYE]

Comment: If you did a Wye-Delta transform on just R2, R4, R6 - what would that give you?

Comment: Do it step by step. Note that R5 is parallel to the rest of the network. Then reduce the problem tho that rest of the network. Note, that it would be symmetrical.

Comment: Note: All resistors having equal value lets you do another important simplification.

Comment: brhans: Transforming Wye -> Delta for R2, R4, R6 would give me R1, R3, R5. Right? If I'm right, do the resistance values change from 3K to something else or do they stay the same?

Comment: Buy few resistors and measure

Comment: Doing that transform would give you another delta, with each of its resistors in parallel with your existing delta. Simplify that down to a single delta, and you're almost there. This works even for differing values of resistors, although having them all the same does allow you so make some other simplifications.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Here's a clue - what can you say about Vx and Vy?

Comment: Vy is the center of Wye, Vx is the top of Delta? I'm not really sure since I've solved only basic resistor networks so far. Would transforming Wye to Delta and then solving Delta for R = 3000 be right (3 resistors in total instead of 6)?

Comment: Imagine looking at that network from the left looking at node A. Rotate what you see until R2 is horizontal then ask whether there are in fact two centres to two different wyes.

Comment: I'm still not sure - do appreciate your clues though.

Comment: Remove R5 and redraw the circuit as a bridge with R2 as the middle joining element. If you don’t understand, try googling Wheatstone bridges and, remember, all resistors are the same value.

Answer (score 0):

When the resistors are all equal, then due to symmetry, R2 can be removed. From then on, it’s trivial – just a straight-line series-parallel combination.